# Showing results regarding Cayley Transform

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

> Let $\Xi$ be the set of all real $n\times n$ which do not have $1$ as an eigenvalue. Consider the mapping
>
> \begin{equation}\phi:\Xi\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},\quad \phi(A)=(A-I)^{-1}(A+I).\end{equation}
>
> Prove that $\phi(A)\in\Xi$ and that $A$ is skew-symmetric if and only if $\phi(A)$ is orthogonal.

I have managed to show the later part of the question as follows:

> $(\implies)$Let $A$ be skew-symmetric: \begin{align}\phi(A)\phi(A)^T&=(A-I)^{-1}(A+I)(-A+I)(-A-I)^{-1}\\
> &=(A+I)(A-I)^{-1}(-A+I)(-A-I)^{-1}\\
> &=-(A+I)(A-I)^{-1}(A-I)(-A-I)^{-1}\\
> &=-(A+I)(-A-I)^{-1}\\
> &=(-A-I)(-A-I)^{-1}=I\\\end{align}
> Hence $\phi(A)$ is orthogonal.
>
> $(\Longleftarrow)$ Let $\phi(A)$ be orthogonal:
> \begin{align}\phi(A)\phi(A)^T&=I\\
> (A-I)^{-1}(A+I)[(A-I)&^{-1}(A+I)]^T=I\\
> (A-I)^{-1}(A+I)(A+I)&^{T}((A-I)^{-1})^T=I\\
> (A-I)^{-1}(A+I)(A^T+&I)(A^T-I)^{-1}=I\\
> (A+I)(A^T+I)(A^T&-I)^{-1}=(A-I)\\
> (A+I)(A^T+I)=&(A-I)(A^T-I)\end{align}
> We know that we require this last line to commute, and we can see that to have these commute we require that $A^T=-A,$ i.e. we require $A$ skew-symmetric:
> \begin{align}(A+I)(-A+I)&=(A-I)(-A-I)\\
> -(A+I)(A-I)&=-(A-I)(A+I)\\
> (A+I)(A-I)&=(A-I)(A+I).\end{align}
> Therefore $A$ is skew-symmetric $\iff$ $\phi(A)$ is orthogonal.

I am pretty confident that my $\implies$ is correct, but would like a sanity check on the proof for $\Longleftarrow$.

As for showing that $\phi(A)\in\Xi,$ I am unsure how to tackle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We compute:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\phi(A)-I
&=(A-I)^{-1}(A+I)-I\\
&=(A-I)^{-1}[\ (A+I)-(A-I)]\\
&=2(A-I)^{-1}\ ,
\\[3mm]
&\qquad\text{ so}
\\
\det(\phi(A)-I)
&=2^n\det(\ (A-I)^{-1}\ )
\\
&\ne 0\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
(in characteristic $\ne 2$, yes, we are working over reals,) so $1$ is not an eigenvalue.

---

The first implication is ok.

For the second implication ($\Leftarrow$), just open the parenteses in $(A+I)(A^T+I)=(A-I)(A^T-I)$ when reaching this point to get $2(A+A^T)=0$.

Comment: Ah alright, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Debby If you find this answer helpful, you may upvote it and accept it.